# Class template argument type deduction in C++17 - compilation problems

Tags: g++, c++17

I'm following Kate Gregory's C++ course on Pluralsight and understand that C++17 introduced a feature for compilers to deduce the type in a template, however the code below returns the error: missing template arguments before 'numbers'

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector numbers{ 0, 1, 2 };
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the MinGW gcc compiler (version 6.3.0) and using "g++ -std=c++1z *.cpp" in the command prompt, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I know I can fix it by declaring the type but I wanted to check in case I miss out on other C++17 features through some basic error I'm making.

Comment: Could you please provide the error you got. In my platform with g++ and -std=c++17 it compiled without any error.

Comment: The error I receive is - In function 'int main()':
Vector.cpp:11:9: error: missing template arguments before 'numbers'
  vector numbers{ 0, 1, 2 }; (with a squiggle below numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK (but I suggest not to use `using std::vector`).

The problem is your compiler, g++ 6.3.0, that is too old to support the feature you're trying to use: [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and deduction guides.

[You need g++ 7 or newer](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I use the MinGW Installation Manager and that seems to be held back at 6.3.0 for some reason